# Subplots Frequency Plots

Tags: python

I've been struggling to generate the frequency plot of 2 columns named "Country" and "Company" in my DataFrame and show them as 2 subplots. Here's what I've got.

```
 Figure1 = plt.figure(1)
 Subplot1 = Figure1.add_subplot(2,1,1)
```

and here I'm going to use the bar chart                                                                              `pd.value_counts(DataFrame['Country']).plot('barh')`
to shows as first subplot. 
The problem is, I cant just go: `Subplot1.pd.value_counts(DataFrame['Country']).plot('barh')` as Subplot1. has no attribute pd. ~ Could anybody shed some light in to this?

Thanks a million in advance for your tips,

R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create `Figure` and `Axes` objects separately, and you should probably avoid initial caps in variable names, to differentiate them from classes.

Here, you can use `plt.subplots`, which creates a `Figure` and a number of `Axes` and binds them together. Then, you can just pass the `Axes` objects to the `plot` method of `pandas`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))

pd.value_counts(df['Country']).plot('barh', ax=ax1)
pd.value_counts(df['Company']).plot('barh', ax=ax2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas' plot method can take in a Matplotlib axes object and direct the resulting plot into that subplot.

```
# If you want a two plots, one above the other.
nrows = 2
ncols = 1

# Here axes contains 2 objects representing the two subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=(8, 4))

# Below, "my_data_frame" is the name of your Pandas dataframe.
# Change it accordingly for the code to work.

# Plot first subplot
# This counts the number of times each country appears and plot
# that as a bar char in the first subplot represented by axes[0].
my_data_frame['Country'].value_counts().plot('barh', ax=axes[0])

# Plot second subplot
my_data_frame['Company'].value_counts().plot('barh', ax=axes[1])
```

Comment: tnx a million :)